# Are there any jQuery plugins or libraries for structuring HTML into printable pages?

Tags: jquery, pdf, css, printing, media-queries

Thanks for looking!

### Background

I am working on a project that uses the (excellent) [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa) library which accepts a page of HTML and then prints it as a page (or pages) to a PDF.

Rotativa runs on ASP.NET MVC3+ and the standard, I suppose, is to render your dynamic page using a Razor View which Rotativa grabs and places into a PDF.

### Problem

I am finding Razor to be a bit clunky for the job and am much faster at using jQuery to accept (JSON) data and transform that data into structured and styled page elements.  Since Rotativa allows me to run JavaScript on the page before that page is cast to a PDF, I would like to use jQuery rather than Razor.  In either scenario, I need a way to properly gauge size of elements as they are placed so that on an 8.5" X 11" page, I can properly place headers, footers, page breaks, page numbering, etc.

### Question

I am thinking that I will just have to roll my own plugin for this but, before doing that work, is there already a library or plugin for jQuery that does this?  I searched (on Google) for such a plugin, but didn't have much luck.

Thanks again.